# How to remove rows with certain values from Jtable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a Jtable that I've loaded with values from a .csv file, but it creates a new row for every instance of 5/13/2013 that shows up in the file, like so:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/phdTs.jpg]

I'd like to remove all rows with this info from the table, but am not sure how to do so. Any suggestions for me?

Here's my code to add the data to the table, if it helps:

```
    while (inputStream.hasNext()) {
        String data = inputStream.next();
        String[] values = data.split(",");
        tableModel.insertRow(tableModel.getRowCount(), values);
    }//end of while block`
```

To reiterate and be completely clear, I want to remove every row that contains "5/13/2013" from the table completely. And I'm using the deafault table model, by the way.

Comment: Well, you could just look for the data value, or maybe there's only one element in the array or you could skip every odd line - Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: It might be helpful to see the data

Comment: Maybe a `RowFilter`?

Comment: Why remove the row? How about not adding the row to the table to begin with? All you need is a simple if statement in you looping code to ignore the line when it only contains a single value. Also, why is the table header "Date and Time" if you never display the date?

Comment: Well I originally wanted to display Date and Time in the same cell but couldn't get it to do so. Eventually figured I would just ignore the date completely and change the heading to time because I couldn't figure it out. When I tried to just ignore the line containing the date, it would remove the time and sensor value as well because they are all in the same line in the table. Couldn't figure out why date was displaying in a separate row so i wanted to just remove the rows after adding them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up applying a for loop and an if statement to get this working for me.

```
        //remove rows with instances of "5/13/2013"
        for (int i = 0; i < tableModel.getRowCount(); i++) {
            if (((String)tableModel.getValueAt(i, 0)).equals("5/13/2013")) {
                tableModel.removeRow(i);
            }//end of if block
        }//end of for block
```

It's worked well for me and has gotten rid of each of those rows. Hopefully this may help someone else out.

Answer (score 0):

```
while(i < tableModel.getRowCount()) {
    //if the value at (i, 0) match the specified value the row will be removed
/*
    if the row removed all row will move up and their index will be changed
    so you have to add a condition if the value from the table doesn't match 
    the specified value the iterator i will iterate by one to jump to the next 
    row
*/

if (((String)tableModel.getValueAt(i, 0)).equals("5/13/2013")) {
    tableModel.removeRow(i);
}else {
    ++i;
}

}
```